# System Error Running U-SQL Script Locally

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

When I attempt to run a U-SQL script locally, I get the following error :

```
Start : 7/1/2016 12:53:49 PM
Initialize : 7/1/2016 12:53:49 PM
GraphParse : 7/1/2016 12:53:49 PM
Run : 7/1/2016 12:53:49 PM
Start 'Root' : 7/1/2016 12:53:50 PM
End 'Root(Success)' : 7/1/2016 12:53:50 PM
Start '1_SV1_Extract' : 7/1/2016 12:53:50 PM
End '1_SV1_Extract(Error)' : 7/1/2016 12:53:50 PM
End '1_SV1_Extract(Error)' : 7/1/2016 12:53:50 PM
Completed with 'Error' : 7/1/2016 12:53:50 PM
Execution failed with error 'Failed to start vertex host : 'System.ComponentMode
l.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid applicati
on for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startIn
fo)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.VertexExecutionHost.Start()'
1_SV1_Extract Error : 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The sp
ecified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startIn
fo)
   at Microsoft.Analytics.LocalRun.VertexExecutionHost.Start()'
'
Execution failed !
```

I can run scripts in Visual Studio that execute in Data Lake Store, I get the error only when trying to run scripts locally.

I'm using Visual Studio 15 Community on 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Windows 7 64-bit, please make sure you have VS 2015 updated 2 installed and also this UCRT update:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50410

If that still fails, could you please try to open a cmd shell, then try to run
"your project\bin\debug[A long hex string]\localvertexhost.exe" and see if it runs OK?

Comment: I already have both of those updates installed. When I run it in the command line, I get the same error: "...is not a valid Win32 Application"

Comment: The application is a Windows 64-bit native application.  Since you mentioned that you are using 64-bit Windows 7, the reason that windows gave this error could be that the file itself is corrupted somehow (virus ?).   Maybe you can try to reinstall the ADLA Tool to see if that helps.   Meanwhile, after reinstall, please make sure you "build clean" the solution.

Comment: Another coworker is having the same problem which makes me think it must be something that isn't working with our environment

Comment: Ah, it's our fault. This is actually a bug we have fixed (the linker set the default required OS level to minimal of Windows 8) and I thought the fix was already included in the currently available release.  But unfortunately it didn't catch that. The next release will be out soon and it will have this fix.

To verify that,  open a command shell, then use dumpbin /headers localvertexhost.exe,  in OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES, there's  "6.02 subsystem version", which is windows 8.   The coming release, it will be 6.01 for Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, yes that does seem to be the problem, the subsystem version is 6.02. Thank you for the help

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49504
This new version contains the fix.  Please have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 32-bit Windows 7?  The U-SQL local run requires 64-bit Windows to work.

Sincerely,
Yu Dong

Comment: I am using 64-bit, I'll add that to the original question